# Wordpress URL - Need to remove a GET parameter

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there are a lot of threads for `.htaccess` URL rewriting, but my case seems to be a bit different and I have tried a lot but it doesn't work.

**My current URL:** `http://example.com/forest/trees/?type=perennial`

**What I need is:** `http://example.com/forest/trees/perennial`

I just need to remove the `?type=` from the URL.

*EDIT: The URL may contain hyphens `-` between strings at any point (except the domain name ofcourse). It can be `dense-forest` or `non-perennial` too.*

It's a custom code and plugin, so can't modify it. I just need the URL beautified.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

What I've tried so far in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /forest\/trees\/\?type=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ \/forest\/trees\/%2\/? [L,R=301]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^\/forest\/trees\/([^/]*)?  /forest/trees/?type=$1 [L]
```

---

My current Wordpress .htaccess is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance. :)
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^forest/trees/([^/]+)$ /forest/trees/?type=$1

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Now URLs like `http://example.com/forest/trees/perennial` will internally redirect to `/forest/trees/?type=perennial` and then to Wordpress Dispatcher `/index.php`.

Comment: The term `perennial` is a variable. Can contain anything. Can you modify your answer to match any string? Possibilities are `oak`, `great-banyan`.

Comment: My mistake I forgot it. It's fixed now ;)

Comment: It didn't work.. I get a 404 - Page not found error. :-/

Comment: If you entenr `http://example.com/forest/trees/?type=perennial` it works but `http://example.com/forest/trees/perennial` (no `/` at the end) doesn't ?

Comment: Correct.. 
This works: `http://example.com/forest/trees/?type=perennial`
This doesn't: `http://example.com/forest/trees/perennial`

Using this before WP index rewrite: `RewriteRule ^forest/trees/([^/]+)$ /forest/trees/?type=$1`